# How to return the array after push in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, object

Below is the function that searches the keyword and return the path in the array,
Function works, but returns same array, append path not returning,
can please how to return the result,

```
module.exports.getFilesRecursively = function (directory) {
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
      try {
          const filesInDirectory = fs.readdirSync(directory);
          var result=[1,2];
          for (const file of filesInDirectory) {
              const absolute = path.join(directory, file);
              if (fs.statSync(absolute).isDirectory()) {
                _this.getFilesRecursively(absolute);
              } else {
                   fs.readFile(absolute, function (err, data) {
                      if (err) throw err;
                      if (data.indexOf('TODO') >= 0) {
                        result.push(absolute);
                        console.log(result)// returns [1,2,"file1.js", "file2.js"]
                      }
                  });
              }
           }
           resolve(result); // but returns [1, 2]
      }
      catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `resolve(result)` in the `readFile`' s callback with if condition.

Something like changing

```
if (data.indexOf('TODO') >= 0) {
    result.push(absolute);
}
```

into

```
if (data.indexOf('TODO') >= 0) {
    result.push(absolute);
    if (result.length === 4) {
        resolve(result)
    }
}
```

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

`fs.readFile` is an asynchronous funtion and returns immediately and will do it's work in parallel. So while reading the file the loop will also continue and will be probably faster. As result the `resolve` will be called while the file is still read.
As you already use `async, await` you can easily refactor your code and wait in the loop for `readFile` to be finished.

```js
...
} else {
   const data = await fs.readFile(absolute);
   if (data.indexOf('TODO') >= 0) {
      result.push(absolute);
      console.log(result)// returns [1,2,"file1.js", "file2.js"]
   }
}
...
```

For me this is much more readable and you can get rid of the error handling and leave it to the outer `try/catch`